# mod_rewrite to redirect from https to http

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I access my site through `https`, Firefox asks to allow my webhost's certificate and then I get redirected to my webhost's index page.

I have not asked my webhost to provide me with `https` so I would like any request to `https` be redirected to `http`. I have tried these different methods but Firefox still asks for certificate approval and then get redirected to my webhost's index page. My webhost has Mod_rewrite enabled (apache 2.2) but these lines do not work :

How can I redirect to my website rather than to my webhost's ?
(Ports 80 and 443 are open.)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.org/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.org/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That is not going to work**, I'm afraid :(

Secure channel (SSL) has to be **fully established BEFORE** HTTP part of HTTPS gets involved.

In other words, you cannot rewrite it like that without establishing a secure connection first. In your situation it will always ask you to accept webhost's certificate before any of such rewrite rule will have a chance to start.

You need proper (your own) SSL certificate .. or another hosting company (that will not have HTTPS at all).